# Using Laravel Mongodb GeoWithin

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

Here's a sample code on how to use GeoWithin which I got form https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

```
$users = User::where('location', 'geoWithin', [
'$geometry' => [
    'type' => 'Polygon',
    'coordinates' => [[
        [
            -0.1450383,
            51.5069158,
        ],       
        [
            -0.1367563,
            51.5100913,
        ],       
        [
            -0.1270247,
            51.5013233,
        ],  
        [
            -0.1450383,
            51.5069158,
        ],
    ]],
],
]);
```

Problem: I want to use my own coordinates, which are stored as an array, but have no idea how to implement them into the query.

Here's the json for the coordinates I have, it is in the Shop model.

```
"bounds" : [
    [
        0.4614208, 
        179.7144413
    ], 
    [
        -0.812961, 
        178.5828495
    ], 
    [
        -2.0210651, 
        -178.890295
    ], 
    [
        0.2307123, 
        -177.5719357
    ]
],
```

Here's what I have tried so far. Does not work.

```
$users = User::where('location', 'geoWithin', [
'$geometry' => [
    'type' => 'Polygon',
    'coordinates' => [$shop->bounds],
],
]);
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
        $cor = [68.4632557093602 , 28.715530938537317];
        $cor1 = [ 94.3909900843602 , 28.56125448653838];
        $cor2 = [93.5999744593602 , 15.31161517706943 ];
        $cor3 = [66.0902088343602 , 14.462218496054646 ];
        $cor4 = [68.4632557093602 , 28.715530938537317];

                  $bars = modelname::where('location', 'geoWithin', [
                    '$geometry' => [
                        'type' => 'Polygon',
                        'coordinates' => [
                            [
                               $cor , $cor1 , $cor2 , $cor3 , $cor4
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ])->count();
  echo $bars ;
```

this code is working and $cor means coordinates